# Checking a wide table for nulls

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query, null

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Test if any fields are NULL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14864/test-if-any-fields-are-null)

I am new here. I have a table with 70-odd columns. Is there a way I can check the number of rows with at least one null value in any column other than writing something like `...WHERE Col1 IS NULL OR Col2 IS NULL OR...`? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** The table is on a MS SQL Server 2008 instance. The columns in the table are of different datatypes.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max);

SELECT
   @SQL = IsNull(@SQL + ' OR ', '') + QuoteName(Column_Name) + ' IS NULL'
FROM
   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
   Table_Name = 'YourTable'
   AND Table_Schema = 'YourSchema';

EXEC ('SELECT Count(*) FROM YourSchema.YourTable WHERE ' + @SQL);
```

Another way:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF; -- deprecated in SQL 2005 - 2012, will eventually be removed

SELECT Count(*) FROM YourSchema.YourTable WHERE NULL IN (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 ... Col80);
```

And yet another way, assuming your column names don't have space character in them:

- In SSMS, navigate to the table in the object browser and drop open the column list. Drag the "Columns" folder to a query window. Use search and replace to change all the spaces in the selection to `IS NULL OR`. Prepend the following code and run it!

  ```
  SELECT Count(*) FROM YourSchema.YourTable WHERE [put modified column list here]
  ```

Comment: What is the alternative to `...WHERE NULL IN...` if we don't want to `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;`?

Comment: There is no alternative. You could unpivot if it's *THAT* important to you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any syntactical shortcut that lets you do this.

Here's an approach that uses dynamic SQL and the system catalog view [`sys.columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx):

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT
    @sql = COALESCE(@sql + N' OR (', N'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[mytable] WHERE (') +
        QUOTENAME(c.name) + N' IS NULL)'
    FROM sys.columns c
    WHERE
        (c.object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[mytable]')) AND
        (c.is_nullable = 1) --AND
        --(c.name NOT IN (/* Excluded column names */));

EXEC(@sql);
```

Comment: Thank you! I am still trying to wrap my head around this dynamic SQL example. Can you please explain the `@sql` part? I know the `coalesce` function and tried to separate the arguments out by comma location, but I am confused. What are the various `N'`s for?

Comment: @Anon: The `@sql = ...` part gets run once per row returned by the query -- the first time, however, the variable is `NULL`, so we initialize it to `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` (this could be done in the `DECLARE` statement instead). Each subsequent time, it only concatenates the column name with the condition. The use of `N` in front of string literals signifies that the literal is a Unicode string -- SQL Server allows Unicode object names, so when doing dynamic SQL, it's a good idea to always use Unicode strings for maximum compatibility.