# Directly acessing the NULL bitmap of a row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-internals

I was reading the question [Checking a wide table for nulls](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20398/2397) and I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow directly access the **NULL bitmap** of a row to fast check if a row contains NULL values. Would that be a reliable technique?

(From my reading, there might be issues with the newly introduced SPARSE columns since SQL Server 2008, but can't tell for sure.)

Comment: As well as sparse columns you would also have to consider dropped and altered columns that have the `NULL` bit set but which are no longer part of the table. There is no easy way to access this anyway. The only way I know of is `DBCC` commands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't. Besides, this is a very very very misguided effort. Since you've already loaded the **page** in memory, you have already paid the price for *any* row and *any* column on that page. This is a given for any row oriented storage. The price for fetching the page *overwhelms* the price of looking up values in the page.

If you want to optimize for retrieving the value (including whether it is NULL) for only a specific column then what you are asking for is columnar oriented storage, which is [an entirely different game](http://rusanu.com/2012/05/29/inside-the-sql-server-2012-columnstore-indexes/).